# Cannot remount system (read only) as read/write on my Android TV Box using the adb shell

Tags: android, adb, mount, television

> I am trying to change the access rights of the file system at root
>   level (/) (or /system level) from read only to **read/write** on my Android TV Box
>   using adb and the shell. My Android TV Box runs as Android 7.1.2
>
> A **mount** command returns :
>
> ```
> 1|q201:/ $ mount
> rootfs on / type rootfs (ro,seclabel)
> ...
> ```
>
> The following command :
>
> ```
> 1|q201:/ $ mount -o rw,remount mtd:rootfs /
> ```
>
> returns :
>
> ```
> mount : '/' not in /proc/mounts
> ```
>
> A **cat /proc/mounts** command returns :
>
> ```
> q201:/ $ cat /proc/mounts
> rootfs / rootfs ro,seclabel 0 0
> ...
> ```
>
> The following command :
>
> ```
> 1|q201:/ $ mount -o rw,remount /
> ```
>
> returns :
>
> ```
> mount: 'rootfs' not user mountable in fstab
> ```
>
> Starting adb at root level  `adb root` does not change anything.
>
> Could someone kindly help?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot remount the `rootfs` in `rw` mode, but only the system partition.

to see what is mounted:

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

or the available partitions:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Answer (score 0):

Device must be rooted!

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /
```